# Visual Basic Files

Tags: vba

I'm working with Visual Basic with a Form and I need to save the data from the form into a new or existing file.

When I create or save a .xls file, it doesn't split de data (what I mean is that is everything in one column)

[image]

Also, I find really difficult to save the data properly (it always overwrite the existing data)

This is the saving code:

```
Sub Save()

10 Rem Save RANDOM
20 Open "C:\CCA\Final\prueba.xls" For Random As #1 Len = 50
30 Put #1, , regi
40 Close #1
50 MsgBox "File saved"

End Sub
```

This is the data that I'm saving:

```
Public regi As camion


Type camion
tipo As String * 45
peso As String * 2 '
End Type
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247412)):

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = tipo
oSheet.Range("B1").Value = peso


oBook.SaveAs "C:\prueba.xls"
oExcel.Quit
```

It would be easier if you just use VBA to create a macro.*
Create a Excel file and just use this code:

```
Cells(y, x) = data1  
Cells(y2, x2) = data2
```

Really recommend you to do it this way, because it's way easier.

*I hope a VBA solution is okay for you, at least you used the VBA tag.